# Running SQL Server Profiler 24/7

Tags: sql, sql-server-profiler

I have low-level traces that I used to SQL Profiler to create and I would like to run these traces 24/7.
So for I have the trace result imported to a table in the database and It stop running when I close the SQL Profiler instance.
Is there a way to make this runs 24/7 in the background?

Comment: be cautious of running the sqlprofiler 24/7, this can cause performance issues as the log size grows

Comment: I am running the trace on another sql server